# How to find the fault column from an oracle error ORA-12704

Tags: oracle, mismatch

I support a product that uses an oracle database. One of our queries is creating an error "ORA-12704: character set mismatch error".

I asked their dba to look at the oracle logs and he tells me he cannot identify the column and that the only thing he can find in the oracle logs is this:

```
Trace file /opt/oracle/oradata/PRESC/diag/rdbms/presc_s_v1/PRESC/trace/PRESC_ora_123128.trc
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning and Real Application Testing options
ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
System name:    Linux
Node name:      ******
Release:        3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
Version:        #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 23:06:41 UTC 2016
Machine:        x86_64
Instance name: PRESC
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 1
Oracle process number: 64
Unix process pid: 123128, image: oracle@******


*** 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** SESSION ID:(83.13298) 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** CLIENT ID:() 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** MODULE NAME:(mtxagent@****** (TNS V1-V3)) 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** CLIENT DRIVER:() 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960
*** ACTION NAME:() 2019-05-15 13:54:23.960

ORA-12704(1):  dty=1 typ=0 flg=00000000 xfl=000A0000 bfl=128 bfc=64 csfm=2 csid=2000
ORA-12704(2):  dty=1 typ=3 flg=00030300 xfl=00000100 bfl=0 bfc=0 csfm=1 csid=31 styp=0
```

This is the error we get in our product logs:

```
24/04/2019 15:59:12 Vision64Database                 ERR [46975217760576] SQL Error: ORA-12704: character set mismatch
24/04/2019 15:59:12 Vision64Database                 ERR [46975217760576] Query: SELECT a.ApplicationName, a.ApplicationVersion, COUNT (a.ApplicationName) FROM Applications a INNER JOIN SoftwareInventory s ON ((s.Version IS NULL) AND (a.ApplicationVersion = '') AND (a.ApplicationName = Name)) GROUP BY a.ApplicationName, a.ApplicationVersion UNION SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(11) */ a.ApplicationName, a.ApplicationVersion, COUNT (a.ApplicationName) FROM Applications a INNER JOIN SoftwareInventory s ON ((s.Version IS NOT NULL) AND (a.ApplicationVersion = s.Version) AND (a.ApplicationName = CONCAT (CONCAT (Name, ' '), Version))) GROUP BY a.ApplicationName, a.ApplicationVersion
```

Offending SQL Query suitably formatted (does not add information !):

```
    SELECT a.ApplicationName
         , a.ApplicationVersion
         , COUNT (a.ApplicationName)
      FROM Applications a 
INNER JOIN SoftwareInventory s 
        ON ((s.Version IS NULL) 
       AND (a.ApplicationVersion = '')
       AND (a.ApplicationName = Name))
  GROUP BY a.ApplicationName
         , a.ApplicationVersion
     UNION
    SELECT /*+ dynamic_sampling(11) */ 
           a.ApplicationName
         , a.ApplicationVersion
         , COUNT (a.ApplicationName)
      FROM Applications a
INNER JOIN SoftwareInventory s
        ON ((s.Version IS NOT NULL)
       AND (a.ApplicationVersion = s.Version)
       AND (a.ApplicationName = CONCAT (CONCAT (Name, ' '), Version)))
  GROUP BY a.ApplicationName
         , a.ApplicationVersion
         ;
```

I will most likely find the faulty column name by hand but it's going to be a hastle, and I'd like to find a way to get it from the oracle logs for the next times it happens with any query.

Any hint someone?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table definition, and the query that is causing the issue.

Comment: also, I would avoid the use of the `CONCAT` function; it's very limited. Instead, using the concatenation operator `||`. e.g. `name || ' ' || version`. It's much easier to read and therefore maintain.

Comment: do any of the columns in your query have a datatype of NVARCHAR2?

Comment: Wild guess: `Applications.ApplicationName/Version` and `SoftwareInventory.Name/Version` columns are declared as `VARCHAR2` and `NVARCHAR2`, respectively, or vice versa. Maybe all columns are defined as `NVARCHAR2`, then the literals in the query (which by default are `VARCHAR2`) need to be converted to `NVARCHAR2`. See [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12704_character_set_mismatch.htm) for a discussion of the compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks guys but as my original post mentions it, i'm not interested into finding the solution to what's wrong in this query, my goal is to find a way on how to identify the faulty column from Oracle logs, if it's possible. 

Still I'll check your hints, it might actually make my life easier! :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @collapsar

Comment: I can't find a way to identify the column in the trace file (in fact, I can't even identify the SQL statement in the trace file).  However, if you have the original query, if you run it in an IDE or even SQL*Plus it will tell you which column causes the error.  Most IDEs show the relevant column by moving the cursor to it.